# Change of variables for parabolic co-ordinates

Tags: integration, limits

What's the best way to see the change of limits (i.e. a mechanical process) for parabolic coordinates? For example, in deriving the beta function we can write

$\Gamma(u)\Gamma(v) = \int_{t=0}^{\infty}\int_{s=0}^{\infty} e^{-(t+s)}t^{u+1}s^{v+1} \mathrm{d}t\; \mathrm{d}s$

and then we make the change of variables $t=xy$ and $s=x(1-y)$.

My problem is I don't see how this changes the limits to be $0<x<\infty$ and $0<y<1$. I've tried drawing a picture but it doesn't help.

Is there some general rule for deriving the change of limits in situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have new variables defined by $t=xy$ and $s=x(1-y)$, then conversely you have $$x=s+t$$ and $$y=\frac{t}{x}=\frac{t}{s+t}$$

Now plug in the limits you have. If both $s$ and $t$ go from $0$ to $\infty$, then so does their sum $x$. And if both are positive, then that fraction $y$ must be between $0$ (for $t=0$) and $1$ (for $s=0$). The special case $s=t=0$ is not covered, but it is irrelevant for your integration: you can integrate over the open range, thus excluding this point. The inequalities in your question already express as much.